# Play scala missing paramater type error

Tags: scala, dictionary, openid, playframework-2.2, redirect

Im trying to connect to my openid provider through play scala.

I use `openID.redirectURL` and than send the answer to a map function but i am stuck at this

> error : missing paramater type.

My code

```
OpenID.redirectURL(myProviderUrl,ComeBackUrl).map( url => Redirect(url)).recover{ case Thrown(error) => Redirect(routes.Application.login)}
```

The error is at the url that the map recieves from the `redirctURL` function ( which retrives `Future[string]`) .

I saw this code lots of times at the web and on play's docs, but somehow i can't compile it.

Comment: Can you post this line as it actually exists in your code, including the `recover`?

Comment: I add it to my question now, but i dont think thats the problem..

Comment: What is `Thrown` ? Shouldn't you mean `Throwable` ?

Comment: No, its play.api.libs.concurrent.Thrown . Its a promise state containing an exception. Actually now i found its deprecated and i should use Failure instead.. But still not work.

Comment: Using `case t: Throwable` compiles just fine for me.

Comment: Did try it, but still error on the url : missing parameter type

Comment: Maybe im using wrong imports?? Can u pls write your imports?

Comment: Just `play.api.libs.openid.OpenId`, `play.api.mvc._`, and `play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._`. Try isolating this in a minimal controller.

Comment: I feel so dumb... I used play.api.OpenID. Well thats what you get when working without IDE. Now its somhow get into endless redirection loop... Well i will manage it alone but man thanks a lot!!! How do i vote u up here ?

Comment: Sorry for reposting but i didnt want to open new question. Right now it conpiles byt every question goes through this always goes to recover. My provider dont get any request.. You have any idea?

Comment: You should log the exception to see what the problem is.

Comment: How can i log throwable? Pretty new to scala..

Comment: `{case e: Exception => println(e.getMessage) }` or `e.printStackTrace` for more information.

Comment: Well, the exception is : ConnectException: General SSLEngine problem to...

Comment: Ive serached on it, and i think this problem occurs due to the fact that i created self signed certificate to my provider and added it to my computer. Somehow when i approach to my provider through my browser it works, but here it fails... Any suggestions?